# How to make animation visible fully html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

I try to make the added content newly visible fully.
But when the animation processing and the container disallow to overflow, the specific animation doesn't show to the user.
I think that trying to moving up the respected element would be good solution.
But I couldn't solve this issue.
For example, I'm gonna implement like the below.
Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p9j6hy4m/27/)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
      <div class="item-area" v-for="item in items">
         <div class="item" @click="toggleMenu(item)">
           {{item.name}}   
         </div>   
         <transition name="menu">
           <ul class="menu" v-if="item._showMenu">
             <li>Menu1</li>
             <li>Menu2</li>
             <li>Menu3</li>
           </ul>           
         </transition>
      </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
  data:{
      items:[{
        name:"Item 1",
        _showMenu:false
      },{
        name:"Item 2",
        _showMenu:false
      },{
        name:"Item 3",
        _showMenu:false
      },{
        name:"Item 4",
        _showMenu:false
      },{
        name:"Item 5",
        _showMenu:false
      },{
        name:"Item 6",
        _showMenu:false
      }]
  },
  methods:{
    hideMenu(){
       this.items.forEach(item=>{
        this.$set(item, "_showMenu", false);
       })
    },
    toggleMenu(item){
         if(!item._showMenu){
          this.hideMenu();
       }
       this.$set(item, "_showMenu", !item._showMenu);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app{
  padding:10px;
  background: #999;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.list{
  position:relative;
}

.list .item-area{
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.list .item{
  padding:10px;
}

.list .item:hover{
  background:#eee;
}

.list .item-area .menu{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#01a6F4;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  z-index:100;
  list-style:none;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.menu-enter-active, .menu-leave-active {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.menu-enter, .menu-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform:scaleY(0);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
      <div class="item-area" v-for="item in items">
         <div class="item" @click="toggleMenu(item)">
           {{item.name}}   
         </div>   
         <transition name="menu">
           <ul class="menu" v-if="item._showMenu">
             <li>Menu1</li>
             <li>Menu2</li>
             <li>Menu3</li>
           </ul>           
         </transition>
      </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

When clicking item1, 2, 3, 4, it shows the menu correctly.
But clicking item5, item6, the container cuts the specific part.
To fix the issue, I would like to move up the element to show the animation smoothly.
How could I achieve this thought?

I've tried like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p9j6hy4m/34/).
But I want to move up item5 less than when clicking item6.

Comment: Do you want a solution where the dropdown shows below the container?

Comment: Similar of that. But I want to move up reference element to show dropdown fully.